# Database Modelling of Type, Subtype Relation

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to model the type and subtype relationship described [here](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Type_line).

The best approach I could come up with would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Card_Types (
       card_type varchar(12) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Subtypes (
       card_subtype varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY
       card_type varchar(12) REFERENCES Card_Types
       PRIMARY KEY (card_subtype, card_type)
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics (
       card_name varchar(141) PRIMARY KEY,
       -- more to come?
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics_Types (
       card_name varchar(141) REFERENCES Card_Characteristics,
       card_type varchar(12) REFERENCES Card_Types,
       PRIMARY KEY (card_name, card_type)
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics_Subtypes (
       card_name varchar(141) REFERENCES Card_Characteristics,
       card_subtype varchar(15) REFERENCES Card_Subtypes,
       PRIMARY KEY (card_name, card_subtype)
);
```

Sample data for Card_Subtypes:

```
| card_subtype | card_type |
|--------------+-----------|
| Human        | Creature  |
| Rogue        | Creature  |
| Werewolf     | Creature  |
| Thopter      | Creature  |
```

Sample data for Card_Characteristics_Types:

```
| card_name                     | card_type |
|-------------------------------+-----------|
| Kruin Outlaw                  | Creature  |
| Ornithopter                   | Artifact  |
| Ornithopter                   | Creature  |
| Akroma, Angel of Wrath Avatar | Vanguard  |
```

Sample data for Card_Characteristics_Subtypes:

```
| card_name    | card_subtype |
|--------------+--------------|
| Kruin Outlaw | Human        |
| Kruin Outlaw | Rogue        |
| Kruin Outlaw | Werewolf     |
| Ornithopter  | Thopter      |
```

What I don't like about this model is that sometimes you're encoding the type information in two places. If a card has the subtype Human, then it is clearly a creature, so there is no need to store that information in the Card_Characteristics_Types table.

So I guess I could only write to the types table if the card didn't also have a subtype of that type. But that's a constraint that the user would have to uphold.

I know I could accomplish some of this w/ triggers, but I'm trying to stay as close as possible to the relational model. Is there a better way to model this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I figured out The Right Way to model this. It was staring me right in the face in the form of rule **205.3c**:

> If a card with multiple card types has one or more subtypes, each
>   subtype is correlated to its appropriate card type.

```
CREATE TABLE Card_Types (
       card_type varchar(12) PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Subtypes (
       card_subtype varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Subtypes_Types (
       card_subtype varchar(15) REFERENCES Card_Subtypes
       card_type varchar(12) REFERENCES Card_Types,
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics (
       card_name varchar(141) PRIMARY KEY,
       -- more to come?
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics_Types (
       card_name varchar(141) REFERENCES Card_Characteristics,
       card_type varchar(12) REFERENCES Card_Types,
       PRIMARY KEY (card_name, card_type)
);

CREATE TABLE Card_Characteristics_Subtypes (
       card_name varchar(141),
       card_subtype varchar(15),
       card_type varchar(12),
       PRIMARY KEY (card_name, card_subtype)
       FOREIGN KEY (card_name, card_type) REFERENCES Card_Characteristics_Types,
       FOREIGN KEY (card_subtype, card_type) REFERENCES Card_Subtypes_Types
);
```

Comment: It's a little unconventional to use the same columns two or three times in different foreign keys, but I can't think of an example that breaks it nor of a simpler way to achieve all of the same constraints - so +1 for the question and +1 for the answer!

Comment: My only objection is that you don't need the first 3 simple fk `REFERENCES` in the `Card_Characteristics_Subtypes` table. The (last) 2 compound foreign keys are enough.

Answer (score 3):

**Important Caveat:**  You need to look at the link OP provided!  It uses the words `type` and `sub-type` as jargon in a way which is similar to, but different than what programmers or even data modellers would do.

---

The issue is that the rules state that if a card has a sub-type, that sub-type must be valid for the given (super)type.

Since not all types have sub-types in this model, you need to have a many to many association between the list of types and individual cards.  At the same time, you need to have a many to many association between the list of possible sub-types and individual cards.

You are in a bit of a relational model rock and hard place.  It depends on how you want to optimize your model.  You can optimize for storage or you can optimize for retrieval.

*Optimizing for Storage:* You can eliminate the redundancy by linking types without sub-types directly to cards.  When you have a type that has sub-types, don't link the type, link the sub-type instead.  This avoids redundancy and the potential inconsistency of parents and children contradicting each other.  It sucks for data retrieval, however.

*Optimizing for Retrieval:* You could instead link all types and sub-types (when applicable) to cards and then you have redundancy to manage - either with triggers or some other kind of application logic.

There is one more option you could try, which is a kind of combination approach and which manages to push the complexity into a more rarely used corner of your application.  In the third way, you collapse type and sub-type into a single table with an involuted relationship (self-reference).  Now when you assign a type or sub-type it automatically implies any parents of that thing.

Given the rules requirement for enforcing membership in the type before allowing membership in a sub-type, I would be inclined to just live with the redundancy.  You need a business rule that says you can't have the sub-type if you don't have the type.  That's the kind of business rule that needs to be in code anyway.

Comment: I like option one better than option two. Option three sounds interesting, but I feel like it might be kind of a hack. Is that a common pattern in the relational theory?

Comment: Option one are both fine.  Just remember that option one means more complex code in the retrieval and less complex code in the maintenance.  Option two is the other way around.  Option three isn't a common pattern at all.  It's taking the data model and turning it sideways a little bit by looking at types/subtypes in a very abstract way.  It may not be a _hack_ but it might suffer from being _elegant_ - which can be worse.

Comment: Hmm, what do you think about [Celko's solution](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/Trees-in-SQL)?

Comment: I really like Celko's method for handling hierarchical data.  In fact, if you look through my answers here and on SO you'll find that I've recommended it more than once. To me, Celko's method makes moving up and down the tree easier.  It doesn't address your primary concern, which is relating to parents and (optionally) children consistently.  You could use Celko's solution as the implementation for _option three_.  That would be a good way to achieve the advantages of that approach.

Comment: Bah, I thought I had things figured out, until I saw line 205.3m. Types Creature and Tribal have the same list of subtypes. Now I'm lost again. Thoughts?

Comment: I think I'm going to go option two w/ two triggers. One, on subtype insert, ensures that that card already has an appropriate type. And two, on type delete, that cascades that delete to any subtype associations that are no longer valid. However, I'm still left with the feeling that there must be a better way to model this.

Comment: As far as 205.3m goes, I'd be inclined to interpret that as saying they have identical looking, but distinct sub-types.  As far as the nagging feeling - There are some things which relational is brilliant at enforcing and some which it just isn't meant to handle.  There are almost always business rules that need some procedural code to enforce them.

Comment: What do you think about the answer below?